# process.env is undefined after using .env file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I have created an application using node.js & protractor. the following start script is used in the package.json file for running my application

```
"start": "protractor conf/conf.js"
```

I have created a .env file and add one sample variable `TestManaf='1234556'`
But it shows error like 'the value is undefined'.

After this, I have directly added `TestManaf='1234556'` in the start script.

```
"start": "set TestManaf='1234556' && protractor conf/conf.js"
```

It is working fine. Why .env file not supported? is any additional configuration required?

Comment: are you writing at any time to the proccess.env? this package takes care of it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the package `dotenv`

use the following command:

```
npm install dotenv
```

First thing you should do in your file is load the dotenv env vars, put this line as soon as possible in your import hierarchy.

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

You can see more information about using this package [in the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)